# Authentication failure with postfix and sasl using sasldb

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sasl

I'm really not sure what my issue is. I've checked several guides, and I am sure I have set this up correctly, including config fails, restarting the service, permissions etc. OS is Ubuntu Server.

When testing with `testsaslauthd -u myemail@mydomain-p password`

I only ever get: `0: NO "authentication failed"`

My postfix.conf (comments deleted):

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_use_tls=no
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 172.16.0.0/16
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
mydomain = mydomain
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

My smtp.conf for sasl

```
pwcheck_method:auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5
```

My saslauthd config:

```
START=yes
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="sasldb"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/run/saslauthd"
```

All permissions are correct and I have restarted the services to ensure. mail.warn shows the following:

```
warning: unknown[myip]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

What can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Test the SASL Mechanism that your installation was compiled with or supports:  `saslauthd -v`